# 'stack build' fails on windows with missing regex-pcre dependency

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

$ stack build
Error is below. I have

$ stack --version
Version 2.7.3, Git revision 7927a3aec32e2b2e5e4fb5be76d0d50eddcc197f x86_64 hpack-0.34.4

How would I know if it were installed non-standard? Where do I find and how to install the dev system package on windows?

Thanks

```
regex-pcre   > Configuring regex-pcre-0.94.4...
tf-random    > Registering tf-random-0.5...
regex-pcre   > Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_1.22.5.0_ghc-7.10.3.exe: Missing dependency on a foreign
regex-pcre   > library:
regex-pcre   > * Missing C library: pcre
regex-pcre   > This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
regex-pcre   > provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
regex-pcre   > already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
regex-pcre   > --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871998/duckling-installation-on-windows-missing-c-library-pcre-on-windows?!